# Partitioning Google Maps according to area

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google map developed from Google map API.I have 12 areas in DB (eg: 1, 2…).I want to partition map with this Areas. Is it possible.?
[image]

Comment: Areas in ottawa region(canada)

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTables_geocoder_PointInPolygon.html)?

Comment: Yes,how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the coordinates of the intersecting points, you can draw polylines on the map.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple